# How to reuse functionality in wix installer

Tags: wix, installation

I am new to WIX. I have created an installer to create web site on IIS.I need to use this website installer inside two more wix project. e.g in another project I am creating window service and want create website as well in same project and in another project I want to create database and this website as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put shared functionality inside a wixlib project.

You basically put shared functionality into <Fragment> tags and use a <Element**Ref**> tag to include the fragments in your main wix project.

You probably already use the WixUIExtension which looks like it's basically just a wrapper around the ui.wixlib. You incorporate part of the ui wixlib when you do <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir> and then everything in the fragment of [WixUI_Installdir.wxs](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_InstallDir.wxs) is merged into your main wix project at compile time. (I think the preprocessor does this)

So if you can identify portions of your installer that are shared between your multiple installers, you can make a wix lib that includes multiple InstallComponent.wxs and a way to reference them into your main install. Generally this can be with UIRef, RegistrySearchRef, or in the case where there is no real Ref element you can use, just include a description property at the top of your Fragment something like

```
<Property Id="ComponentNameInclude" />
```

then in your installer project you can reference this property to bring in everything in the fragment this property belongs to.

```
<PropertyRef Id="ComponentNameInclude" />
```

I would suggest reading through the wix source (I linked the github to one of the files) to get a better idea of how wix itself makes use of some wixlibs.